# What is the reason why my media queries wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get rid of the media query "media screen and (max-width: 500px)" because i want my default settings to be for any screen smaller than 500px and i shouldn't have to specify screen width for my default settings. However whenever i get rid of this media tag it ruin/messes up the rest of my media tags and the set up of those screens at those sizes. How do i set the default for my set up to be mobile devices under 500px and then keep the rules for the bigger screens? The bigger screens need to stay the same layout. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

i {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hamburger {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

section {
  border: grey solid 1px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 3px
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .social {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  div {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-top: grey 1px solid;
  }
  li,
  .social {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .logo,
  h1 {
    display: inline;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    right: 10%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    right: 10%;
    top: 20px;
  }
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  section {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 2%;
    border-top: grey 1px solid;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}

.logo>img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/6eb75550-4d51-47fd-8ec1-d216b5da5e5c/M4sq-logo.jpeg" /></div>
    <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hamburger">&#9776;</div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="navbar">Home</li>
      <li class="navbar">Products</li>
      <li class="navbar">About</li>
      <li class="navbar">Help</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-apple-alt fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
      <p>
        We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App, the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry. This is the Uber of Apples!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
      <p>
        Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the Facebook of bail bonds!
      </p>
    </section>
    <section class="product">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
      <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

      <p>
        Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></li>
      <li class="social_icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not just set a min width AND max with for your query?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett whenever I get rid of the first media tag and then set min and max width for the other tags it messes up my headers and nav bar.

Comment: Hmm. I see now, very strange indeed. Give me a few mins, i'm looking into it.

Comment: All I can find is that you have `header`, `.menu.` and `.social`  with rules defined in your queries, but not outside of your queries. If you want them to have default values, you have to define them in your CSS (not in queries). Then, use the queries to modify those values.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thanks, i pretty much just ended up starting from scratch with my css and doing what you said by setting the default value for everything and then defining them if they needed changes in the queries.

Comment: Probably the best way... even if it is a bit more work. It always helps to have defaults in case some random device get confused about something in the future. Hope it works well for you this time!

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

i {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hamburger {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

section {
  border: grey solid 1px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 3px
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .social {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 501px)and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  div {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-top: grey 1px solid;
  }
  li,
  .social {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .logo,
  h1 {
    display: inline;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    right: 10%;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: row;
    right: 10%;
    top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  section {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 2%;
    border-top: grey 1px solid;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}

.logo>img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

This should be what you're looking for.

The reason it wouldn't work is that you max-width 500 has some styles that are not needed for higher widths; thus, if you want the max-width 500 to be the default, those have to be changed for the higher widths.

Since it may not be immediately clear, what I changed was:
 1. moved the styles from the media query max-width 500px to outside of any query
 2. changed the 2nd query to include min-width 501px
 3. added flex-direction: row; & margin-left: 0; to both of the remaining queries

I'm fairly sure your css can be optimized btw, but since that's not the scope of the question I won't do that for now.